# Laravel passport with Amazon Alexa

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel website and I am trying to add Amazon Alexa Smart Home skill to it. Currently I am trying to create a lambda skill to access the passport in Laravel. It wants to login to the website which is correct, but it keeps coming back with this:

{"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}

From what I can tell it wants a user assigned to each client. The Alexa skill can only be one client. In the Alexa Skill I have it assigned to a Client_id and a secret. This one client has to be assigned to all my users that want to use the Alexa app.

There is not much I can find on using Amazon Alexa with Laravel. I have found this site https://github.com/develpr/alexa-app by Kevin Mitchell which I will be looking into once I get this to work.

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this with passport or any good information on using Laravel with Alexa I would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured out the passport problems I was having.

1:If your doing a Alexa skill you need to create a new client with the user_id change to NULL. This will allow multiple users to use the same client.

2: Alexa skill require a scope. So you need to add one in the AuthServiceProvider.php where it as has you add Passport::routes();

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes();   // added with passport

    Passport::tokensCan([      // add for scope
        'MyScope' => 'My scope description'
    ]);
}
```

If you need help figuring this out I used this video at the end to test. He has others for setting up passport:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LElAbzmZJU4

Sure hope this helps other from spending many days on figuring it out.